# sass undefined variable in react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Hello im trying to import my sass variables in react project to other scss.
I made new scss in src/sass/_variable.scss.
And im trying to import it in src/Pages/Home/Home.scss.

I was trying to use @import and @use and still have error.
When im trying to @use i got this error Error: Undefined variable.
When im trying to @import i got this errror: Not Found.
The path its good.
I tried with node sass and dart sass.
The weird thing is that it only works when im import sass in same directory..

Answer (score 0):

```
@import '../../Style/Var.scss';
```

Write it at the top of the file scss

Please check this link it will help you.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import